# Automated question answering (FAQ) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence, nlp

I would like to build a very simple application - Automated FAQ. I searched the internet and found some information about different approaches but there is no .Net specific example. Do you have som experience of building such application or maybe know some .Net specific examples? It would be very interesting to take a look at one. 
Here is an example http://193.108.42.79/ikea-us/cgi-bin/ikea-us.cgi
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you consider an *Automated FAQ*? What's the process behind it? I can't come up with an idea of it... Like a self sustainable Q&A site like Stackoverflow? Or what?

Comment: i mean like this one http://193.108.42.79/ikea-us/cgi-bin/ikea-us.cgi

Comment: Research "natural language understanding".

Comment: Isn't that what StackOverflow is?  ;>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're trying to build is a [chatterbot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterbot).
There are many ways to go about it, not many of them trivial.
Probably the simplest approach would be to incrementally build an [AIML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AIML) knowledge base together with an AIML platform of your choice ([RebeccaAIML](http://rebecca-aiml.sourceforge.net/) support C#).